# coeffs returns coefficients in a very weird order

Tags: maple

I have a polynomial like this one:

```
p := -1.604609130*10^(-11)*z^9+.1111140258*z^8+3.210741142*10^(-11)*z^7-.3955586214*z^6-2.108471910*10^(-11)*z^5+.6692726719*z^4+5.024523477*10^(-12)*z^3-.8174429322*z^2-3.142106870*10^(-13)*z+.9089252367
```

You see, just a regular polynomial with numeric coefficients. Then I call `coeffs` on it and get this:

```
> coeffs(p, z, 't'); t
                                            -11                
0.9089252367, -0.3955586214, -2.108471910 10   , 0.6692726719, 

                -12                                -11  
  5.024523477 10   , -0.8174429322, -1.604609130 10   , 

                              -11                 -13
  0.1111140258, 3.210741142 10   , -3.142106870 10   
                  6   5   4   3   2   9   8   7   
              1, z , z , z , z , z , z , z , z , z
```

Why on Earth it returns coefficients in such order?! I would expect it to be either from higher powers to lower powers (like in MATLAB) or from lower powers to higher powers (like in Mathematica), but Maple does something absolutely weird. My program depends on the order of coefficients extracted by `coeffs`, so I just can't use it.

Is there a way in Maple to extract coefficients in some sane order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `CoefficientList` or `CoefficientVector` [commands](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=PolynomialTools%2FCoefficientVector) for this.

Note the comments about efficiency relative to using `coeffs` for this, in that help page.

Those commands also have an option for returning the coefficients in reverse order.

```
restart:

p := -1.604609130*10^(-11)*z^9 + .1111140258*z^8 + 3.210741142*10^(-11)*z^7
     -.3955586214*z^6 - 2.108471910*10^(-11)*z^5 + .6692726719*z^4
     + 5.024523477*10^(-12)*z^3 - .8174429322*z^2 - 3.142106870*10^(-13)*z
     + .9089252367:


V := PolynomialTools:-CoefficientVector( p, z );

                           [      0.9089252367]
                           [                  ]
                           [               -13]
                           [-3.142106870 10   ]
                           [                  ]
                           [     -0.8174429322]
                           [                  ]
                           [               -12]
                           [ 5.024523477 10   ]
                           [                  ]
                           [      0.6692726719]
                           [                  ]
                      V := [               -11]
                           [-2.108471910 10   ]
                           [                  ]
                           [     -0.3955586214]
                           [                  ]
                           [               -11]
                           [ 3.210741142 10   ]
                           [                  ]
                           [      0.1111140258]
                           [                  ]
                           [               -11]
                           [-1.604609130 10   ]


L := PolynomialTools:-CoefficientList( p, z );

      [                             -13                               -12  
 L := [0.9089252367, -3.142106870 10   , -0.8174429322, 5.024523477 10   , 

                                -11                               -11  
   0.6692726719, -2.108471910 10   , -0.3955586214, 3.210741142 10   , 

                                -11]
   0.1111140258, -1.604609130 10   ]
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! That's exactly what I need. It's still interesting, though, why `coeffs` (as a globally available function by default) has such a strange behavior.

Comment: @acer what if one wants only the nonzero coefficients, but in a correct order? I think `CoefficientList` will take too much space for some high degree but few terms polynomials and in some applications you do really need only nonzero coeffs, but need the order. I can put a loop and if to remove extra zeros, but I don't think it will be an efficient way to do so after paying the cost of creating that long list in first hand. Any other solution?